# access_log item w/out IP. Starts with "::1 - - [<date>]"

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, http, logging

Looking at our Apache log I see normal requests like:

```
174.133.xxx.xxx - - [20/May/2010:17:36:44 -0700] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2004
```

but every so often i get a cluster of these w/out an IP address.

```
::1 - - [20/May/2010:18:47:21 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [20/May/2010:18:47:22 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [20/May/2010:18:47:23 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

what do they mean and curious what causes them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are normal. ::1 is the IPv6 address for localhost; the OPTIONS requests are part of how Apache manages its child threads.

Answer (score 1):

That's IPv6 localhost - something on your server is making requests to "localhost" and it's resolving to ::1.